# How to replay the same request in cypress?

Tags: javascript, api, request, cypress

I want to test the following use case:

1. I listen for POST API request with `cy.intercept()` method
2. I click the button which executes POST API request
3. I do `cy.wait('@myapi').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);`
4. After that I want to trigger the request again with cypress (like replaying it) and make sure that this time I get the `statusCode` 400 and validate the response body to contain the error message

How to do this in cypress? Any ideas? :D

I tried to do something like this:

```
    cy.intercept('POST', regexHelpers.getCartURIRegex(voucherCode)).as("redeemVoucher");

    cy.get('[data-cy="buttonRedeemVoucher"]').click();

    // cy.wait('@redeemVoucher').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
    cy.wait('@redeemVoucher').then(function(interception) {
      expect(interception.response.statusCode).to.eq(200);
      const url = interception.request.url;
       cy.request({
         method: 'POST',
         url: url,
         headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
       }}).its('status').should('eq', 400);
    });
```

But in this case I get `400` error code - bad request already at the line
`expect(interception.response.statusCode).to.eq(200);`

The first call to API should return 200, but the second call with the same voucher should return 400.

I am confused why is it returning 400 already at this line:
`expect(interception.response.statusCode).to.eq(200);`

[EDIT]

I managed to do this:

```
cy.intercept('POST', regexHelpers.getCartURIRegex(voucherCode)).as("redeemVoucher");

    cy.get('[data-cy="buttonRedeemVoucher"]').click();

    cy.wait('@redeemVoucher').its('request.url').as('voucherUrl').then(function() {
      cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: this.voucherUrl,
        failOnStatusCode: false,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }}).its('status').should('eq', 400);
    });
```

But I don't know how to also check here that first call response code was 200?
Does anybody has an idea? :D

Comment: It works for me running against `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` (but the 2nd status check is for `200` also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the first response call with `.should(callBack)`

```js
cy.wait('@redeemVoucher')
  .should(interception => expect(interception.response.statusCode).to.eq(200))
  .its('request.url').as('voucherUrl').then(function() {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: this.voucherUrl,
      failOnStatusCode: false,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      }}).its('status').should('eq', 400);
  });
```

But your first example would also work, provided you added `failOnStatusCode: false` to the request.

Answer (score 2):

I also did the following which also worked:

```
cy.wait('@redeemVoucher').should(({request, response}) => {
  expect(response.statusCode).to.eq(200);

  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: request.url,
    failOnStatusCode: false,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }}).should((response) => {
      expect(response.status).to.eq(400);
      expect(response.body.errors[0].message).to.eq('Voucher cannot be redeemed: ' + voucherCode);
  });
});
```